# Q: How to set --set-gtid-purged=OFF as a default Export parameter in Mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, database, gtid

Ive recently been playing with Mysql Workbench and the Export function has one little annoying feature that is not needed (by me of course). The set-gtid-purged function is set to AUTO by default in the GUI and it seems everytime you want to export without this parameter - you have to change it to OFF in Data Exports - Advanced options. To make it worse - the setting is not remembered.

Wanted to check if anyone has found a way to set it to OFF permanently for every DB/conenction i make?

I even checked the wb_options.xml file and the feature is set to OFF but this doesn't seem to stop it for some reason.

```
<value type="string" key="wb.admin.export.option:set-gtid-purged">OFF</value>
```

Thanks.

Comment: simi-related... I went through this troubleshooting thinking I had a legacy MySQL server that didn't support set-gtid-purged because it kept throwing an error. Found out that I had configured MySQL Workbench to use the `mysql` binary as `mysqldump`, so of course it complained.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I want to do exactly what you are looking for but in AWS RDS. so for your case what you must do is:

## Solution

1. Update config file Update `/etc/my.cnf` and add

   [mysqldump]
   set-gtid-purged=OFF
2. No need to restart. If you dont have access to that .cnf file then update the update directadmin.conf with the following instruction:

   extra_mysqldump_options=--set-gtid-purged=OFF
3. Is possible to run the following command in shell to achieve point number 2:

   echo "extra_mysqldump_options=--set-gtid-purged=OFF" >> /usr/local/directadmin/conf/directadmin.conf
   service directadmin restart

### Official and useful references

[MySQL Dump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_set-gtid-purged)

[MySQL enable/disable GTID (Global Transaction Ids)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-mode-change-online-enable-gtids.html)

[MySQL extra options during DUMP](https://www.directadmin.com/features.php?id=1112)

Answer (score 9):

I've found a temporary solution for this on Linux/Ubuntu

1. Open /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/wb_admin_export.py
2. Search for "--set-gtid-purged=OFF"
3. Delete or comment that line (#) and the if statement above it.
4. Restart MySQL Workbench

Using windows, the path to the file will vary and I will update my answer if someone can give it to me.

Comment: Mac file location is `/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins/wb_admin_export.py`, line number 1861 and 1862.

Comment: In my case y have only commented the line 1883 (MySQL Workbench 8.0.13)
#if self._compatibility_params:

Answer (score 7):

On a Mac, running Mysql 5.7, I found the following to work:

In Workbench, select:

Server -> Data Export -> Advanced Options

change "set-gtid-purged - Add 'SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED' to the output." from AUTO to OFF

Then export your data.

The exported SQL files should no longer have the line:

"SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN= 0;"

and now it imports successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using only mysqldump in Ubuntu Server

Try append this to etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf

```
set-gtid-purged=OFF
column-statistics=0
```

May looks like this:

[image: mysqldump.cnf setting for set-gtid-purged=OFF and column-statistics=0]